# jQuery- if two elements have certain value then do something

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener

I have two elements, a radio button and a select menu;
I want to remove a class if each of the elements have a certain value

for example: if the select value is `1` and the radio button value is `1` than remove the class.

my issue is how do I listen to two different element type of elements

this is the html file:

```
<div id="select">
  <select name="family_state" class="ff" id="family_state">
    <option value="0">a</option>
    <option value="1">b</option>
    <option value="2">c</option>
    <option value="3">d</option>
    <option value="4">e</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="radio">

  <input id="mimun_a" name="mimun_nosaf" value="1" type="radio" required="" checked="">
  <label for="mimun_a">1</label>

  <input id="mimun_b" name="mimun_nosaf" value="0" type="radio" required="" checked="">
  <label for="mimun_nosaf">0</label>

  <div id="to-hide" class="hidden">
    this is the hidden div
  </div>
```

This is the js file:

```
document.getElementById("mimun_a").addEventListener("click", tryit);
document.getElementById("mimun_b").addEventListener("click", tryit);
document.getElementById("family_state").addEventListener("change", tryit);

function tryit() {
  var select = $("#family_state").val();

  if ($("#mimun_a").is(":checked")) {
    if (select == 1) {
      $("to-hide").removeClass("hidden");
    };
  };
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/davsev/pen/dKXQbK)

Thank's

Comment: What kind of selector is `$("to-hide")`? you mean `$("#to-hide")`. Happens often when mixing jQuery and vanilla JS's `getElementById` where `#` is not a valid selector

Comment: Correct, thank you. ... so silly....

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you remove `;` from if segment ending `}`

```js
document.getElementById("mimun_a").addEventListener("click", tryit);
document.getElementById("mimun_b").addEventListener("click", tryit);
document.getElementById("family_state").addEventListener("change", tryit);

function tryit() {
  var select = $("#family_state").val();

  if ($("#mimun_a").is(":checked")) {
    if (select == 1) {
      $("#to-hide").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  }else if($("#mimun_b").is(":checked")){
     $("#to-hide").addClass("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
  <select name="family_state" class="ff" id="family_state">
    <option value="0">a</option>
    <option value="1">b</option>
    <option value="2">c</option>
    <option value="3">d</option>
    <option value="4">e</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="radio">

  <input id="mimun_a" name="mimun_nosaf" value="1" type="radio" required="" checked="">
  <label for="mimun_a">1</label>

  <input id="mimun_b" name="mimun_nosaf" value="0" type="radio" required="" checked="">
  <label for="mimun_nosaf">0</label>

  <div id="to-hide" class="hidden">
    this is the hidden div
  </div>
```

corrected :

```
function tryit() {
  var select = $("#family_state").val();

  if ($("#mimun_a").is(":checked")) {
    if (select == 1) {
      $("#to-hide").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  }else if($("#mimun_b").is(":checked")){
     $("#to-hide").addClass("hidden");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#family_state').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val()!=0 && $('[name="mimun_nosaf"]:checked').length>0 && 
                     $('[name="mimun_nosaf"]:checked').val()==1)
         $("#to-hide").removeClass("hidden");
  else
        $("#to-hide").addClass("hidden");
});
 $('[name="mimun_nosaf"]').change(function () {
     if ($(this).val()==1 && $('#family_state').val()!=0)
            $("#to-hide").removeClass("hidden");
     else
             $("#to-hide").addClass("hidden");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd use the jQuery selectors instead of getElementById. Somehow, it looks more consistent to me. Also you can select by name. Here is my answer:

```
$("[name='mimun_nosaf']").change(tryit);
$("#family_state").change(tryit);

function tryit() {
  var select = $("#family_state").val();
  var radio_val = $("[name='mimun_nosaf']:checked").val();

  if (select == 1 && radio_val == 1) {
      $("#to-hide").removeClass("hidden");
  };
};
```

You can use also the ".click" event listener, but it will register any click on the radio button. The ".change" listener will register events when the radio button's value is alternated only.